# PHP Laravel Comparison Date(Hour)

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I have 2 hours:

```
$night = "19:00";
$morning = "04:00"; (tomorrow)
```

What i want is, if hour now is between 19:00 - 04:00 the result is `true`,how can i achieve that? Sorry for my broken english,
Thankyou in advance

Comment: A simple check: If the current time is greater than or equal to 19 OR less than equal to 4

Answer (score 0):

Try this using DateTime.

```
$now = new \DateTime();
$current = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$night= $now->format('Y-m-d 17:00');
$morning = $now->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d 04:00');
                
if($night <= $now && $now <= $morning) {
  echo "Yes";
}else{
  echo "No";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use strotime() function from PHP

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$night = "2021-09-08 19:00:00";
$morning = "2021-09-09 04:00:00";
if(strtotime($night)<= strtotime($now) && strtotime($now) <= strtotime($morning)) {
    //do some work
} else {
    //do something
}
```